# Create a Disk in Azure New Portal is not working , old portal I could do it easily

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, vhd

I'm not even sure why azure even has a GUI Website.  It is starting to feel a bit ridiculous when the old  manage.windowsazure.com  I could powershell up a VHD, and then very easily use a Storage and container and Add the image and then choose from gallery of my own images.

NOW I read that in May 2017 a lot of things with the old portal are going away.  I created a Storage Account  `myvmblobs`  and then a container `mywincontainer` and then I uploaded a VHD , tmppro2.vhd is sitting there as a VHD Blob

URL  https://myvmblobs.blob.core.windows.net/mywincontainer/TMPPRO2.VHD

So I read that I could create a Disk image from powershell  ( I have to no way to do it with website portal.azure.com )

```
Add-AzureDisk 'tmppro2' -MediaLocation https://myvmblobs.blob.core.windows.net/mywincontainer/TMPPRO2.VHD -Label 'OS' -OS "Windows"
```

However,  I don't know if the Label or OS is important...

Add-AzureDisk : BadRequest: The storage account with the name myvmblobs as specified in the VHD URI https://myvmblobs.blob.core.windows.net/mywincontainer/TMPPRO2.VHD does not exists in the current subscription

Comment: Do you mean you want to upload VHD to azure storage account use powershell?

Comment: No,  I did that before to old portal recently and that worked fine,  I used the Gui in the container of portal.azure.com to upload .vhd to the container.

Comment: I just want to create a VM from the VHD that is sitting in the new portal in my container

Comment: The VHD from where?   the VHD create from azure or on-prem?

Comment: VHD was created on-prem and then uploaded to Azure portal

Comment: Oh, I see people saying that  Add-AzureDisk is for Classic VM and Storage.. Ughhh  - how can I easily create a disk in azure from the vhd that is in a container in new portal.azure  ?

Comment: I believe that would be `Add-AzureRmVMDataDisk` or `Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk'.

Comment: we can use template to create a new VM, or use powershell.

Comment: Maybe the template is faster and easier.

Comment: I see the answer below,  thx guys .     Hey I'm a full-stack developer ... and I write tons of c# and javascript etc...  but I guess this seems a bit ridiculous when the old portal made it work without powershell - IDK,  I guess if this is the direction that we are headed,  seems like I should not even be able to upload a vhd within the portal.azure ..    crazy to me

Comment: @JohnBaxter    we can use some tool to upload VHD to Azure, like Azure Storage Explorer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, we can use PowerShell or template to create new VM in Azure ARM module.

About PowerShell, here is a example script(use existing VHD):

```
$rgname = "jason-newgroup" 
$loc = "japaneast" 
$vmsize = "Standard_DS1_v2" 
$vmname = "jason-newtest2" 
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmname -VMSize $vmsize 
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name ("jason-newtest45") -ResourceGroupName $rgname 
$nicId = $nic.Id 
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nicId 
$osDiskName = "jason-newtest" 
$osDiskVhdUri = "https://jasonnewgroupdisks912.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/jason-newtest201681285042.vhd" 
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -VhdUri $osDiskVhdUri -name $osDiskName -CreateOption attach -Linux 
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $loc -VM $vm
```

Use template to create Azure VM:

Here is the [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd).

[image]

**Update:**

We can use **azure storage explorer** to upload VHD to Azure:

[image]